# BeautifulSoup/Regex: Find specific value from href

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

Using the below code, and trying to find the value at the end of the href. Is there a way to extract the href, and find values after `page=` in BeutifulSoup/Regex?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import re

request = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fun?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

findNext = soup.find("a", class_="next_page")
print(findNext)
```

Getting this output:

```
<a class="next_page" href="/quotes/tag/fun?page=2" rel="next">next »</a>
```

Note: Want to extract `2` from the above or any other number which may arise.

Comment: So get the `href` value and then use `re` to get whatever is on the right of the equals sign.

Comment: `re.find('page=(\d+)',findNext['href'])`

Comment: You can split it into an array and then select the last item in array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` to find the page number:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
request = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fun?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')
page_nums = re.findall('(?<=page\=)\d+', str(soup.find("a", class_="next_page")))[0]
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

request = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fun?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

findNext = soup.find("a", class_="next_page").attrs['href'].split('page=')[1]
print(findNext)
#Result is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex you could do something like,

```
    let url = "/quotes/tag/fun?page=2";
    let urlParam = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
    let matches = urlParam.match(/=(.+)/);
    let username;
    if (matches) {
        username = matches[1];
    }
    return username;
```

Comment: I like the set approach.  Also, this is the second time in the past 15 minutes I see someone using `let`.  Where is the documentation for `let`?  First I saw it in JavaScript, and now I see it in Python.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon  check this out for `let` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = '<a class="next_page" href="/quotes/tag/fun?page=2" rel="next">next »</a>';
var regex = /(?<=href=\")[^\?]+\?page=(\d+)(?=\")/
var match = regex.exec(text);

console.log("**href => " + match[0] + " **page => " + match[1]);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tawKH2/2)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can use `URL` constructor, `.search` to get query string parameters, `String.prototype.split()` at `"="` character and `Array.prototype.pop()`

```js
var param = new URL('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fun?page=1')
            .search.split("=").pop();

console.log(param);
```